# login y error con java, spring-security y thymeleaf

Tags: java, login, thymeleaf, spring-security

Necesito ayuda para escribir el código necesario para poder colocar mi pagina de login personalizado y mi pagina de error 403, les muestro el código que estuve trabajando hasta el momento.
PDT: Estoy trabajando con Java en IDE ECLIPSE, Spring Boot y thymeleaf.

Class WebConfig

```
package com.example.holaspring.web;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
        
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        var slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("es"));
        return slr;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        var lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }
    
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registro) {
        registro.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registro) {
        registro.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registro.addViewController("/login");
        registro.addViewController("/errores/403").setViewName("errores/403");
    }
}
```

Class SecurityConfig

```
package com.example.holaspring.web;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExceptionHandlingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig{
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService user() {
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("{noop}123")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("{noop}root")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }
    
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain adminLogin(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/editar/**","/agregar/**","/eliminar","/guardar").hasRole("ADMIN");
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").hasRole("USER");
                })
                .formLogin(login -> {
                    login.isCustomLoginPage();
                })
                .build();
                                
    }

}
```

Class Controller

```
package com.example.holaspring.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.example.holaspring.domain.Persona;
import com.example.holaspring.servicio.PersonaService;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Controller
@Slf4j
public class ControladorInicio {
    
    @Autowired
    private PersonaService personaService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String inicio(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        var personas = personaService.listarPersonas();
        log.info("ejecutando el controlador Spring MVC");
        log.info("usuario que hizo login:" + user);
        model.addAttribute("personas", personas);
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/agregar")
    public String agregar(Persona persona) {
        return "modificar";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/guardar")
    public String guardar(@Valid Persona persona, Errors errores) {
        if(errores.hasErrors()) {
            return "modificar";
        }
        personaService.guardar(persona);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/editar/{id_persona}")
    public String editar(Persona persona, Model model) {
        persona = personaService.encontrar(persona);
        model.addAttribute("persona",persona);
        return "modificar";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/eliminar")
    public String eliminar(Persona persona) {
        personaService.eliminar(persona);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    
}
```

login.html que esta dentro de mi carpeta src/main/resources

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        
        <form method="POST" th:action="@{/login}"></form>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </body>
</html>
```

403.html que esta dentro de mi carpeta src/main/resources/templates/errores

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Acceso denegado</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div>Acceso denegado. No tienes permiso para ver esta pagina o ejecutar esta acción
        <a th:href="@{/}"> [[#{accion.regresar}]] </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yo intenté colocar este código para poner mi pagina de inicio personalizada:
Clase SecurityConfig

```
package com.example.holaspring.web;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExceptionHandlingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig{
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService user() {
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("{noop}123")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("{noop}root")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }
    
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain adminLogin(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/editar/**","/agregar/**","/eliminar","/guardar").hasRole("ADMIN");
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").hasRole("USER");
                })
                .formLogin(login -> login.loginPage("/login"))
                
                .build();
                                
    }

}
```

Pero me sale un error el siguiente error al acceder a http://localhost:8080/login
[image: too many redirections]

Y luego intenté colocar esta línea de código para colocar mi pagina de error 403:

```
exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/errores/403");
```

pero me sale lo mismo que la imagen.

Comment: En la clase SecurityConfig te falta agregar la anotacion EnableWebSecurity abajo de la anotacion Configuration. Esto no se si arregla tu problema pero es algo a tener en cuenta